# Java Override in Inherited Class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

The issue im facing is that whenever someone wants to .switchOff() a SmartDevice, if it is a SmartFridge object it should Override the switchOff() method in the SmartDevice class.

The issue is that java is giving me the following error: The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null

and I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

```
@Override
public void switchOff() {
    if(this.getCurrentTemperature()!= null) {
            this.setSwitchedOn(true);
            //if the object is  SmartFridge leave switchedOn value to true

        }
    }
```

The inherited class:

```
package SmartHomeApp;

public class SmartFridge extends SmartDevice{

    private double currentTemperature;


    public SmartFridge(String name, double location, boolean switchedOn, double currentTemperature)
    {

        super(name, location, switchedOn);
        setLocation(location);
        setName(name);
        setSwitchedOn(true);
        setCurrentTemperature(currentTemperature);
    }

    public double getCurrentTemperature(){ return currentTemperature;}
    public void setCurrentTemperature(double value){ currentTemperature = value;}
```

Smart Device Class:

```
public class SmartDevice {
    private String name;
    private double location;
    private boolean switchedOn;

    public SmartDevice(String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
        setName(name);
        setLocation(location);
        setSwitchedOn(switchedOn);
    }

    //YOU CANT ACCESS the 'private classes' so you need to GET them
    public void setName(String value) {name = value;}
    public void setLocation(double value) {location = value;}
    public void setSwitchedOn(boolean value) {switchedOn = value;}

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public double getLocation() {return location;}
    public boolean getSwitchedOn() {return switchedOn;}

    public void switchOn() {this.switchedOn=true;}
    public void switchOff() {this.switchedOn=false;}
```

Comment: "The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null" -  function `getCurrentTemperature` returns `double`, which can't be null. So you can't compare it to null.

Comment: double is a primitive, not an object. You can use Double instead.

Comment: So how do I check if this object is empty then? (doesn't have currentTemp variable on it)

Comment: what is "empty"? Is 0 "empty", what if the temperature actually is 0? Can there be 'no temperature'?

Comment: @luk2302 I have a SmartHome, that can take in the SmartDevice and SmartFridge. Lets say if I perform the switchOff() method. How can the method check wether its SmartDevice or a SmartFridge?

Answer (score 0):

The type which you're checking against "null" is not an object. This kind of type are primitives and Java sets a default value for them.

You should check this article for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html